# How can we restrict a mp3 file to be played in other application in Android

Tags: android, audio

Requirement is application will download some mp3 files and that are stored in external storage. We need to restrict those files to be played in any other media player provided by android.

Comment: why do you want the restriction. Should leave that to the user to decide.

Comment: As audio are specific to the app and requirement is it should be played in other player

Comment: you can use media player in your app and play the sound. But you should leave it to the user to decide to choose the player you want.

Comment: Reghunandam I agree and implemented as the same till now but the requirement is different, Have added media scanner concept here but still user can browser those folder and files are accessiable

Comment: @Binod did you find solution to your problem. I am also having similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it you only want your mp3 files to be played by your own app. Correct?

If that's the case then you have a problem with external storage as it has 'public' access status. Any app can access any file anywhere in external storage.

The closest you can get to restricting media files in external storage is to create a file called `.nomedia` in the same directory. This will prevent the media scanner from adding the files to the media content provider so other apps won't see them by default. Anybody using a file manager app, however, will be able to find and play the files with any media player they choose.

If you really want to restrict the files to your own app then you need to save them to internal (private) storage. Even than, a phone which has been rooted will allow access to any app's private storage area so there's still no guarantee they'll be 100% restricted.

Comment: .nomedia is just a work around it will avoid from media scanner.

Comment: also we one more work around is downloading in hidden folder with prefix dot. But I hope some kind of encryption is needed in this.

Comment: My mp3 files are 300MB around each and if I store that in internal memory and some how user uninstall the app then also internal memory will not get free.

Comment: @Binod : 1. Yes, `.nomedia` is just a workaround - I explained that. 2. It's not possible to totally hide a directory from a file manager app. Also, encryption may be an option but if someone hacks your apk they can find a way of decrypting. 3. Any data stored in an app's private storage is deleted when an app is uninstalled.